# How do I connect to another person's world on Minecraft Pocket Edition without having the same connection?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I want to join my friend's world but she lives in a different house with different connection. However we do live on the same street.

Comment: i found out i cant

Comment: New answers can be found here if you find this by accident. https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/392029/is-it-possible-to-play-with-someone-who-lives-far-away-on-mcpe/392030

Comment: Procedurally casting close vote per AdamRaichu's comment (after resolving a duplicate chain)

Answer (score 1):

There is a way, but it is a little hard and costs $2.99. There is an app called Minecraft Pocket Edition Multiplayer or something like that. It is $2.99 and on the App store. With that app, you can click host world and follow the instructions it tells you. It will say open Minecraft, then come back to this app, then host and double click home to go back to Minecraft. Your friend will them click join world and find your world by searching the name, Make sure to put a password on if you do this or other people will join!

[Here is a link to the app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/multiplayer-for-minecraft-pe/id609704981?mt=8)