# Is it possible to play with someone who lives far away on MCPE?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, technical-issues, wifi

Me and my friend live far away and both of us have Minecraft PE. We've only been able to play together while connected to the same wi-fi, which doesn't happen often. I'm trying to find a solution, so that we can play together without having to be close to each other

Comment: You can actually just join each other games in the friend's tab as long as you are friends on Xbox.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to play on friend's world in a different part of the country?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/174587/is-it-possible-to-play-on-friends-world-in-a-different-part-of-the-country)

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a server to play with each other. One user-friendly (and free) server hosting service is [aternos.org](https://aternos.org). You must make an account for every server you host, but multiple accounts are allowed and you don't have to give your email. You may have to wait a minute or two after starting the server before you can join it. See their website for more details. Be sure to select Bedrock Edition when in prompts which software you want to use.

---

**Edit:** Another method suggested by [@DisplayNameNotFound](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/users/255284/displaynamenotfound) is to send a friend request to that player. I've never used this feature so I don't know how it works.

Comment: I am most likly wrong here, but could you not just create a microsoft account and send a friend request?
**EDIT**: *that is, assuming they* can *create one...*

Comment: Huh, I didn't think of that but you're probably right. I've never used the friends feature.